# Admin changes themes

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, themes, onchange, html-select

I am making a web-app which admin can change the themes. So I have 2 css files, style.css and style2.css. 
In my application_helper I have

```
def set_themes(themes)
  @themes = themes
end
```

in application_controller I have

```
helper_method :themes
```

And I put this on application.html.erb

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag set_themes %>
```

And in Admin index.html I write a select_tag, like this :

```
Choose themes: <%= select_tag(:themes, options_for_select({"Black" => "compiled/styles", "Green" => "compiled/styles2"}), :onchange => 'set_themes(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)') %>
```

And I got `ArgumentError`. I know that the problem is how I used onchange, because when I change manually from application_helper, it works. But I have no idea how to call methode from application_helper by clicking select_tag.

Can anyone help me? Thank youu :-)

Comment: Can you give the full backtrace and text of the `ArgumentError` exception?

Comment: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of the `set_themes` method requires that the helper method be passed exactly one argument, but in this line:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag set_themes %>
```

you appear to be invoking it without any arguments (i.e., it is equivalent to calling `set_themes()`). You should change the call to `set_themes` in the line above to something else which has the proper arguments, or a direct instance variable, etc.

Comment: So I change to <%= stylesheet_link_tag @themes? @themes: "compiled/styles" %>
It works, but if I change the theme in Admin index, it didn't change

Comment: I don't know enough about your application or what you're trying to accomplish to answer that remaining issue, and it's probably worth a separate question to address it. I hope this problem with the ArgumentError calling `set_themes` is solved, though, and if so please mark as accepted and/or up-vote.

Comment: The thing is, I don't think the helper methode was called from select_tag. I think, it works now because I put @themes? @themes: "compiled/styles" on application.html.

Comment: Right, that was the line that was causing the `ArgumentError` it sounds like